# How to close and start sessions?

Tags: 8, sessions

How do i port following D7 code to D8?

```
  drupal_save_session(FALSE);
  session_write_close();
  drupal_save_session(TRUE);

  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $cookie_lifetime);

  drupal_session_started(FALSE);
  drupal_session_initialize();
```

**Note**: I need to automatically logout user after `$cookie_lifetime` (say 30 sec).

I tried following code

```
$session_manager = \Drupal::service('session_manager');
$session_manager->save(FALSE);
session_write_close();
$session_manager->save(TRUE);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $cookie_lifetime);

$session_manager->setOptions(array('cookie_lifetime' => $cookie_lifetime));

$session_manager->start();

$session_manager->isStarted();

$session_manager->regenerate();
```

Comment: Normally I see code like this associated with [how to impersonate a user account](https://www.drupal.org/node/218104) during a session. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code other than writing/starting a different session? What's the context?

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to automatically logout user after $cookie_lifetime (say 30 sec).

Comment: You'll need something scheduled then. Cron job, AJAX polling, whatever. Unless you want to manually delay the PHP script for the 30 seconds

Comment: I tried following code:
    $session_manager = \Drupal::service('session_manager');
    $session_manager->save(FALSE);
    session_write_close();
    $session_manager->save(TRUE);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $cookie_lifetime);

Cannot i do similar to way it's done in D-7 without AJAX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working piece of code:

```
$session_manager = \Drupal::service('session_manager');

$session_manager->setOptions(array('cookie_lifetime' => $cookie_lifetime));

// Force-start a session.
$session_manager->start();
// Check whether a session has been started.
$session_manager->isStarted();
// Migrate the current session from anonymous to authenticated (or vice-versa).
$session_manager->regenerate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling [user_logout](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_logout/8.2.x) (Drupal 8) will do the trick. This essentially calls `$session_manager->destroy();` as well as invoking other hooks. The [user_logout](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7.x) function also redirected the user in Drupal 7 making it an undesirable programmatic approach, but this has changed.

```
// Call this one liner if you like simplicity and depending on services existing on the
// container.
user_logout();
```

If you want to manually do what user_logout does you can inject the `session_manager`, `logger.factory`, `module_handler` services into your class and call similar methods.

```
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

  // Log some stuff.
  $logger_factory->get('my_module')->notice('User logged out, BAM!');

  // Make sure other modules can clean up after the user!
  $module_handler->invokeAll('user_logout'), [$user]);

  // Destroys the session and removes all cookies.
  $session_manager->destroy();

  // Sets up the anonymous user.
  $user->setAccount(new AnonymousUserSession());

  // And I guess if you will do something else with that anonymous user other than ending
  // the request, then start up and save a session. I don't think you need to do this and I
  // am not sure why you are saving cookie_lifetime on the new anonmyous session.
  // $session_manager->start();
  // $session_manager->setOptions(['cookie_lifetime' => $cookie_lifetime]);
  // $session_manager->save();
```